# Removing Empty or Whitespace strings from an IList<String> in F#

Tags: f#

How do I filter out Empty and WhiteSpace strings from a IList in FSharp? I do not know whether it must be converted to a List first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IList<string>` implements `IEnumerable<string>`, so you can use

```
mylist |> Seq.filter (...)
```